# URLSessionConfiguration Background, timeout issue, working fine in Postman

Tags: swift, timeout, nsurlsession

URLSessionConfiguration Background, execute a failure block within 60 seconds. error saying timeout issue. the same working fine in Postman but the time taken is more than 3 mins to give the result.
I have used the following code.

defaultConfigbgOrderUploads!.timeoutIntervalForRequest = CLTimeIntervalMax

var request = URLRequest.init(url: callURL!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 180.0)

No luck with the above changes as well, it is going to failure block with the timeout issue.

Comment: Use Alamofire library for API!

Comment: A background URLSessionConfiguration object will timeout within 15 seconds. 
If you want the request to wait for 3 minutes, then you can create a URL request with set timeOutInterval of 3 minutes and pass it to a session of type default. 
Please provide more information.